# Woocommerce doesn't list all orders, just the recent ones

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Unfortunately my clients, the Shop owners, updated Woocommerce from 2.1.3 to 2.2.7 after which the complete custom-made template broke, and I had to backup to the old files of 2.1.3.

Now it works, but unfortunately we see only the most recent two orders, though there are definitely much more, and it says also All Orders (644), but I could not list them anyhow, by refreshing the lists, filtering results and so on...

Could you please help, how can I get back all the orders from the database?

Thanks and Best Regards,

Gaspar

Comment: Updating is a good thing! This is one reason why we [override templates within themes](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/), instead of hacking away at core plugin files. Did you re-import the old database, or just the WooCommerce files?

Comment: Just the Woocommerce files, since there were few orders in the meantime, and also some new products updated. I did override the template files with the theme, but my customized Add to Cart did not work on the product page. And the other problem was that the translations were all messed up, since I had to correct it via customizing the mo-po files.

Answer (score 0):

The `[my_account]` shortcode has 1 parameter and that is conveniently, `order_count`.

The default is the 15 most recent posts, but you can change that to any number. *Or* you can change it to `all` and the My Account area will list all orders for a particular customer.

Find the My Account page and change the shortcode in the content to:

```
[woocommerce_my_account order_count="all"]
```

**Edit**

Borrowing from the `my-orders.php` template, we can edit their query to remove the parameter that restricts the orders to only those of the current user. Using the classic WordPress function `get_posts` we can query all order posts.

```
$all_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) );
```

Comment: Thanks Helga, but it doesn't work, it just outputs the shortcode text. I have this already in my Accounts page: [woocommerce_my_account] And I don't need the orders "I" made, but to get back the complete list of orders placed so far.

Comment: You're right, I will edit the shortcode. I think I misunderstood your question. But if you want ALL the orders then you could take a look at the my account shortcode... there is a query for the orders by user, if you removed that parameter you should get all orders. It is simply a `get_posts` for the `shop_order` post type.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I implement it? Should I make a new page-template with it? The echoing of the parameters should be done the same way as the my-orders.php? eg. foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
    $order = new WC_Order();

    $order->populate( $customer_order );

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve. You said you had a custom template before, so I suppose you'd want to duplicate that. And the `my-orders.php` offers a good starting point.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood - I don't want to achieve it in front-end, but to fix the bug in the backend at `..wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order` that happened because of update - and then downgrade to older version because of compatibility

Comment: No, I definitely did not understand. You mentioned templates, so I assumed you meant front-end, but I think I get it now. All the order taxonomies (pending, complete, etc) were converted to post statuses in version 2.2 (see `includes/updates/woocommerce-update-2.2.php`). I suspect this is your problem as the database was changed when you updated to 2.2 and I doubt there is a routine to revert the DB when you downgraded. You could possibly reverse the database updates, but I think it'd be easier to update your templates to support the newer versions of WooCommerce.